# How are Elliptic Curve private and public keys actually used to encrypt or sign data?

Tags: elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, implementation

I've read article after article about curve parameters, generator points, the dot operation, and how you dot the generator point `priv` times to get the `pub` point and voila you have ECC! That's where the articles all stop. But how are the number `priv` and the point `pub` used to modify data during encryption or signing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest application of elliptic curves is **Diffie–Hellman key agreement**.  In a curve $E/k$ over a field $k$ with a standard base point $P \in E(k)$ of large prime order $\ell$ among the $k$-rational points (loosely, the points whose $x$ and $y$ coordinates are in $k$, and not in a field extension of $k$), Alice picks a uniform random scalar $a \in \mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$ and publishes the point $A = [a]P$, the scalar multiplication of the standard base point $P$ by $a$; Bob does likewise with $b$ and $B = [b]P$.  Now Alice can compute $$[a]B = [a]([b]P) = [a\cdot b]P,$$ and Bob can compute $$[b]A = [b]([a]P) = [b\cdot a]P = [a\cdot b]P.$$  They can then both hash this common curve point into a **shared secret** $k = H([a\cdot b]P)$, and use $k$ for symmetric-key authenticated encryption, such as AES-GCM.

This is a high-level overview—there are, of course, devils in the details like how to choose the curve, how to represent the curve points, how to perform the computation, *etc.*, some of which are addressed in [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/).

But what about public-key encryption and public-key signature?

## Encryption

Instead of using a long-term key pair $(a, A)$, when Alice wants to send a message to Bob she can generate a temporary secret scalar $t$, compute a temporary public key $T = [t]P$, compute a temporary session key $k = H([t]B) = H([t\cdot b]P)$, and transmit $T$ as associated data with a symmetric-key AEAD box (authenticated encryption with associated data) under $k$.

Then Bob, on receipt of $T$ and an AEAD box, computes $k = H([b]T) = H([t\cdot b]P)$, and uses that to open the AEAD box.

That's it.  It's just a DH key agreement with a temporary key pair.

## Signature

There are a few different signature schemes out there based on elliptic curves.  For a detailed discussion of some of the design choices that go into conventional elliptic-curve signature schemes, see [djb's blog post on how to design an elliptic-curve signature system](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20140323-ecdsa.html).  Here's a couple of (very different) examples:

### Example 1: [EdDSA: Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#ed25519) (simplified)

This is the general form of the widely used Ed25519 signature scheme, which widely deployed and understood and considered by many to be the modern standard signature scheme.

**Parameters.**
A field $k$, a twisted Edwards curve $E/k: y^2 - x^2 = 1 - d x^2 y^2$ over the field $k$, a standard base point $B \in E(k)$ of large prime order $\ell$, and a hash function $H\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{512}$.

**Public keys.**
A public key is the representation of a point $A \in E(k)$.

**Signatures.**
A signature on a message $m$ is the representation of a point $R \in E(k)$ and a scalar $s \in \mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$ satisfying the verification equation $$[s] B = R + [H(\underline R \mathbin\Vert \underline A \mathbin\Vert m)] A.$$  Here $[s]B$ means scalar multiplication of the point $B$ by the scalar $s$, and $\underline R$ means the bit string encoding of the point $R$.

**Private keys.**
A private key is a secret 256-bit string $k$ chosen uniformly at random.  The 512-bit hash $H(k)$ is split into two 256-bit halves, the first interpreted as a scalar $a \in \mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$ and the second taken as a bit string $h$.

To sign a message $m$, the signer computes the scalar $r = H(h \mathbin\Vert m)$, the point $R = [r]B$, and the scalar $$s = r + H(\underline R \mathbin\Vert \underline A \mathbin\Vert m) a.$$

Verifying that signatures created this way satisfy the verification equation is left as an exercise for the reader.

### Example 2: [BLS signatures](https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs00145-004-0314-9) using pairing-based cryptography

The Boneh–Lynn–Shacham signature scheme uses a function called a *pairing*, which is a bilinear map $e\colon E(k) \times E(k) \to G$ from the group $E(k)$ of $k$-rational -points on a curve $E/k$ with coordinates in the field $k$ to a multiplicative group $G$, typically the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ of integers modulo a prime $p$.

‘Bilinear’ means that if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are elements of $E(k)$, then $e(X + Y, Z) = e(X, Z) \cdot e(Y, Z)$ and $e(X, Y + Z) = e(X, Y) \cdot e(X, Z)$, *i.e.* that addition of two inputs carries through to multiplication of the outputs.  This further means scalar multiplication $[a]X$ the curve carries through to exponentiation $g^a$ in the target group: $e([a]X, [b]Y) = e(X, Y)^{a b}$.

Pairing-based cryptography is not as widely deployed, and its security is not as well-understood, but it admits very short signatures (half the size of Ed25519 with a curve of comparable conjectured security, for example), and it is simple to state.

**Parameters.**
A field $k$, an elliptic curve $E/k$, group $G$, a bilinear map $e \colon E(k) \times E(k) \to G$, a standard base point $B \in E(k)$ of large prime order $\ell$, and a hash function $H\colon \{0,1\}^* \to E(k)$ mapping messages to curve points.

**Public keys.**
A public key is the representation of a point $P \in E(k)$.

**Signatures.**
A signature on a message $m$ is the representation of a point $S \in E(k)$ such that $$e(S, B) = e(H(m), P).$$

**Private keys.**
A private key is a secret scalar $p \in \mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$ such that $P = [p]B$, the scalar multiplication of $B$ by $p$.

To sign a message $m$, the signer simply computes $S = [p] H(m)$.

Verifying that signatures created this way satisfy the verification equation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if the field is limited by $\ell$ then any private key (Alice's $a$, Bob's $b$ or a temporary key of $t$) larger than $\ell$ is equivalent to that key mod $\ell$, right? Basically any scalar you multiply the generator point by has no benefit to being larger than $\ell$? I'm still processing Example 2, maybe a larger scalar matters there.

Comment: Yes: secret scalars are always elements of $\mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$.  Note that $\ell$ is not a property of the field, although it is limited by the size of the field, according to Hasse's theorem—it is a property of the field and the curve, and may vary from point to point in cases of curves like Curve25519 with composite order.  See [an earlier answer I wrote](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51352/49826) for more details on how they are related.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: you've posted an abundance of incredibly useful and helpful on this forum (some of which I actually understood ;-) ).  anyway -- under "Encryption", you wrote `compute a temporary session key =([])=([⋅]), and transmit ` -- seems that there might be typo?  Seems like `=([])=([⋅]P)` might be the intent?  Always intimidating to post a suggested correction to an expert, sorry if I missed the boat here.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, you are absolutely correct: it was a typo!  Fixed.