# How are curve names constructed?

Tags: elliptic-curves, standards

I started with the question: [Brainpool curves](https://neuromancer.sk/std/brainpool/) exist in a variant ending in ..r1 and ..t1. What does it mean?

But there are also "secp.." and "sect.." just like NIST's "..r1" and "k1".

What do all of those mean?

Comment: Related to but not quite answered (bearishly) by https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59964/what-is-the-difference-between-ecdsap-ecdsak-and-ecdsab-in-the-output-of-ope

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The prefix ***sec*** stands for "Standards for Efficient Cryptography" (per the eponymous [group](https://www.secg.org/), in the sense of assembly of experts). ***Brainpool*** stands for the name of [another](https://web.archive.org/web/20180515175923/http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/) assembly of experts.

After this, ***p*** (or ***P*** after *Brainpool*) stands for Prime, and is used for curves with an equation over field $\mathbb F_p$ of prime order. After *sec*, ***t*** is used when the field is $\mathbb F_{2^k}$ for $k>1$, but I don't know why *t* was chosen or if the curves have further properties.

The typically 3 digits that follow are, in decimal, the bit size of the field order (not necessarily the bit size of the curve order, which is different for *sect* curves).

After this, ***k*** stands for Koblitz, and is used for Koblitz curves and, as a generalization, for curves with field $\mathbb F_p$ that have an efficient endomorphism (per [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44647-8_11) paper). ***r*** stands for Random, and is used for somewhat random curves without this property. For Brainpool curves, ***t*** stands for twisted, and I leave it to others to explain what that means.

The last digit(s) form an index in decimal, starting from 1 for the first curve standardized with the same designation before that index.

---

There is also the "NIST curves" of [FIPS 186-4 appendix D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=96). These start with ***P*** (for Prime, meaning as *p* and *r* above combined), **K** (for Koblitz curve on a field binary $\mathbb F_{2^k}$ for $k>1$, combined with *r* above), or **B** (for Binary field $\mathbb F_{2^k}$, combined with *r* above). That's followed by a minus sign or dash, and 3 digits as above. The curves P-UVW match their secpUVWr1 counterparts (P-256 is secp256r1). I did not check in detail but I think that extends to K-UVW for sectUVWk1, perhaps B-UVW for sectUVWr1.

---

Much of the information in this answer is sourced from [sec2v2](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf) of [SECG](https://www.secg.org), sections [2.1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#section.2.1) and [3.1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#section.3.1); and from [FIPS 186-4](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.186-4).

Note: Some other curves are named according to inspiration of the author. For example [Curve25519](https://doi.org/10.1007/11745853_14) got it's name because the prime field has order $2^{255}-19$. By this convention [Curve1174](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/325) would be Curve2519 but I guess the single-digit difference with the pre-existing Curve25519 would have caused endless confusion, so it got it's name from the constant 1174 in it's equation. [Ed448-Goldilocks](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/625) tells it's an Edwards curves and uses a field of order a 448-bit prime with some rare-as-gold property.

Comment: Curve448-Goldilocks is another exception.

Comment: FWIW [_draft_ FIPS 186-5](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/5/draft) if/when adopted will move the specific curves from [appendix D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=96) to a new, separate document SP800-186 -- with the addition of Edwards, Montgomery/X _and_ Weierstrass forms of 25519 and 448, how thorough!