# Why SM2 ECC parameters does not specify cofactor h?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Recently I've been studying the ECC with [the Chinese SM2 standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shen-sm2-ecdsa-02). One question is on standard part 5, parameters definition, it only defines $p, a, b, n, XG,$ and $YG$, but not cofactor $h$.

I found some useful discussion introducing all the parameters mathematics behind: [What is the relationship between p, n, and h](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51350/what-is-the-relationship-between-p-prime-n-order-and-h-cofactor-of-an-ell/51352#51352).It doesn't answer my question: Why SM2 does not specify h, while Key Exchange Agreement Protocol introduce in SM2 part 3 has used it.

On the standard part 1, section 5.2.2, it provides a method to verify Elliptic Curve Parameters. One option process uses to verify $h$ is:

(optional) Calculate $h'=\lfloor((p^{1/2} + 1) ^ 2)/n\rfloor$, and verify $h=h'$

This also means h can be calculated by the equation above. I calculate with an online big number calculator, the result is slightly greater than 1 (not fully equal).

Or have I misunderstood this cofactor? It is calculated instead. Elliptic curve can be perfectly defined only with $p, a, b, n, XG$, and $YG$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Elliptic curve can be perfectly defined only with $p, a, b, n, XG$, and $YG$.

Yes, indeed even though it's not the nicest / most convenient set of parameters, this is sufficient to recover the curve order (using [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm)) and with that the co-factor.

Of course Schoof's algorithm, while efficient, isn't exactly fast nor widely implemented and therefore usually the curve order and co-factor are supplied.

> Why SM2 does not specify h, while Key Exchange Agreement Protocol
>   introduce in SM2 part 3 has used it.

Well, the quality of the linked IETF draft isn't the best, so maybe it was just an oversight.

To answer your question: $h=1$.
This can be verified using the following `sage`-math instructions:

```
F=GF(0xFFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
a=0xFFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC
b=0x28E9FA9E9D9F5E344D5A9E4BCF6509A7F39789F515AB8F92DDBCBD414D940E93
n=0xFFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7203DF6B21C6052B53BBF40939D54123
E=EllipticCurve(F,[a,b])
h=E.cardinality_pari()/n;h
```

where the last one should return the co-factor $h$ as being $1$.

> I calculate with an online big number calculator, the result is
>   slightly greater than 1 (not fully equal).

This formula comes from the [Hasse-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse's_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) (with $q$ being the curve and $p$ being the field order) $$\left|q-(p+1)\right|\leq 2\sqrt p$$ which assuming $q\geq p+1$ is 
\begin{align}
&&q-(p+1)&\leq 2\sqrt p\\
\iff&& q&\leq p+2\sqrt p +1=(\sqrt p +1)^2\\
\iff&& h=q/n&\leq (\sqrt p +1)^2/n
\end{align}
If the last value is barely over $1$, this means that $h$ can only be $1$.

Comment: Appreciate for your reply SEJPM. According to the definition, E.cardinality_pari() will gives the result of $#E(Fq)$, how long will that calculation takes? What is the link between this function and the equation used to obtain $h'$ described in standard, $h′=[((p1/2+1)2)/n] $? Is the last one return 1?

Comment: @Tian `E.cardinality_pari()` is quite optimized, so it took a few seconds on my laptop. This answer used the more standard definition of co-factor from the answer by Squeamish Ossifrage you linked. Can you please locate the formula with $h'$ in the linked IETF draft or link the containing document? I failed to do so and thus didn't follow through on it, as I wasn't sure on a specific piece of notation.

Comment: sorry the notation is on the standard itself, not IETF draft. You may access here at [SM2 Standard Part 1](http://www.gmbz.org.cn/upload/2018-07-24/1532401673134070738.pdf). Equation is at section 5.2.2, process (h). And from here [the SM2 English Version](http://www.gmbz.org.cn/main/postDetail.html?id=20180724110812) you may access all other parts.

Comment: @Tian thanks, this clarified that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ instead of normal parenthesis / brackets were meant. I have clarified on how this works in a new paragraph anyways.

Comment: Awesome! Now things come all together. You really save my day. Thanks a lot.