# ECC with 512bit compatible curves

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, information-theory

I understand that given solutions for solving a discrete logarithm problem are on the order of (2/2), ergo, 256bit private keys based on 25519 or secp256k1 have an effective bit strength of 128bits.

I was wondering if anyone could explain how one can know the largest size private key supported by a curve. Is it to do with the curves prime field? I'm just trying to learn a bit more about ECC.

As people slowly look at RSA 3072+ as archaic and not strong enough, I wonder how long before 128bit strength ECC goes the same way.

Do we have any non NIST (NSA backdoored :) ) curves which support 512 bit private keys (yielding 256bit security?).

Thanks,
John

Comment: First, the NIST curves themselves are most likely not backdoored (we have a question about this on this site), so P-521 should do. Second, have a look at Curve448 ("Goldilocks").

Comment: @SEJPM thanks! I was being a little facetious regarding the NSA. Can I ask you how I can tell the largest key supported by a curve? What's the property of a curve that dictates this?

Comment: The curve order (which is closely related to the size of the underlying field / prime)

Comment: Even better than the kludgey semirigid ‘verifiably random’ short Weierstrass curve P-521 is the nice rigid Edwards curve E-521 found simultaneously by three independent research groups.  But yes, you should use edwards448 instead.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51352 for discussion of the relation of the size of the coordinate field, the order of the curve group, and the cost of attacks, as well as a few other relevant security criteria.

Comment: That said: there is no particular reason to doubt a 128-bit security level today; the main predictable threats beyond unpredictable breakthroughs in cryptanalysis are the possibility of large quantum computers, which would devastate elliptic curve cryptography _and_ RSA, and operational or implementation errors like not doing cryptography at all because it's too inconvenient or costly.  You are probably better off just using X25519/Ed25519 for key agreement/signature, or secp256k1, because there are widely available high-quality low-cost implementations.